# psycopg2.errors.StringDataRightTruncation: value too long for type character varying(2) Django

Tags: python, django, heroku, django-models, django-migrations

**I am deploying my Django website on Heroku and facing this error while migrating.**

My website is up and running on localhost but while deploying facing this error.

**This is my models-**

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db.models.signals import pre_save
from Dipesh_Pal.utils import unique_slug_generator


# Create your models here.
class Home(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=255, null=True, blank=True)
    body = models.TextField()
    CATEGORY_CHOICES = [
        ('NEWS', 'News'),
        ('ANDROID', 'Android'),
        ('PC', 'PC'),
        ('OTHERS', 'Others'),
    ]
    category = models.CharField(
        max_length=20,
        choices=CATEGORY_CHOICES,
        default='OTHERS',
    )

    link = models.URLField(blank=True)
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    thumb = models.ImageField(default='default.png', blank=True)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, default=None, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def snippet(self):
        return self.body[:100]+'...'

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return '/' + self.title


def slug_generator(sender, instance, *args, **kwargs):
    if not instance.slug:
        instance.slug = unique_slug_generator(instance)


pre_save.connect(slug_generator, sender=Home)
```

I am getting this error while migrate-

```
python manage.py migrate
You may have some problem with YouTube
Instagram Followers:  341
You may have some problem with Twitter
Operations to perform:
  Apply all migrations: accounts, admin, auth, contenttypes, home, sessions, sites
Running migrations:
  Applying contenttypes.0001_initial... OK
  Applying auth.0001_initial... OK
  Applying accounts.0001_initial... OK
  Applying accounts.0002_auto_20190226_1249... OK
  Applying admin.0001_initial... OK
  Applying admin.0002_logentry_remove_auto_add... OK
  Applying admin.0003_logentry_add_action_flag_choices... OK
  Applying contenttypes.0002_remove_content_type_name... OK
  Applying auth.0002_alter_permission_name_max_length... OK
  Applying auth.0003_alter_user_email_max_length... OK
  Applying auth.0004_alter_user_username_opts... OK
  Applying auth.0005_alter_user_last_login_null... OK
  Applying auth.0006_require_contenttypes_0002... OK
  Applying auth.0007_alter_validators_add_error_messages... OK
  Applying auth.0008_alter_user_username_max_length... OK
  Applying auth.0009_alter_user_last_name_max_length... OK
  Applying home.0001_initial... OK
  Applying home.0002_home_thumb... OK
  Applying home.0003_home_author... OK
  Applying home.0004_home_trip_number... OK
  Applying home.0005_auto_20190104_0239... OK
  Applying home.0006_auto_20190104_0239... OK
  Applying home.0007_auto_20190104_0242... OK
  Applying home.0008_auto_20190104_0244... OK
  Applying home.0009_remove_home_link... OK
  Applying home.0010_home_link... OK
  Applying home.0011_auto_20190105_1138... OK
  Applying home.0012_auto_20190226_1249... OK
  Applying home.0013_auto_20190228_1615... OK
  Applying home.0014_auto_20190306_1623... OK
  Applying home.0015_auto_20190518_1502...Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 85, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
psycopg2.errors.StringDataRightTruncation: value too long for type character varying(2)


The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 15, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 381, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 375, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 316, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 353, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 83, in wrapped
    res = handle_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/migrate.py", line 203, in handle    fake_initial=fake_initial,
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 117, in migrate
    state = self._migrate_all_forwards(state, plan, full_plan, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 147, in _migrate_all_forwards
    state = self.apply_migration(state, migration, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 244, in apply_migration
    state = migration.apply(state, schema_editor)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/migrations/migration.py", line 124, in apply
    operation.database_forwards(self.app_label, schema_editor, old_state, project_state)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/migrations/operations/fields.py", line 84, in database_forwards
    field,
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/schema.py", line 435, in add_field
    self.execute(sql, params)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/schema.py", line 133, in execute
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 100, in execute
    return super().execute(sql, params)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 68, in execute
    return self._execute_with_wrappers(sql, params, many=False, executor=self._execute)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 77, in _execute_with_wrappers    return executor(sql, params, many, context)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 85, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 89, in __exit__
    raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 85, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
django.db.utils.DataError: value too long for type character varying(2)
```

I already try to change max_length=100 or max_length=255 but doesn't work for me.

I am deploying this app on heroku, here my github project "https://github.com/Dipeshpal/Dipesh-Pal-Django_Website" and I am using this method to deploy web app https://youtu.be/MoX36izzEWY

Please help me to fix this issue, I stuck on the deployment stage.

Comment: Changing it will not help, since it is still there in the migration file. You should inspect the content of `0015_auto_201...` and change that one accordingly.

Comment: How to find `0015_auto_201...` thing and what I need to change. The same thing is working on a local system perfectly.

Comment: probably because on local host, there is no data (yet) in the database, wheres on production, you changed the maximum length, and now you thus need to truncate existing data.

Comment: No, there is data on localhost and I also tried deleting the sqlite database and migrate again on localhost and it is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

In your /migrations/versions folder open the latest .py file. It should have the length adjustments. Something like:

```
sa.Column('body', sa.String(length=2), nullable=True),
```

Change 2 to your desired value and save, upload to Heroku again. Please note that in your case other items in that line will be different from above.